# ctypes imports dll in python but it doesn't work

Tags: python, dll, ctypes, visa

I need to import a C library in python (TLDFM, a library to drive a deformable mirror by thorlabs), I'm doing it with

```
>>> mirror=ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('TLDFM_64.dll')
```

but even if I don't have errors, then it doesn't work properly. It's folder is in the system path and the dependences needed by this library (the visa by national instruments) are in the same folder. The point is that I have nonsense results, for example:

```
>>> mirror.TLDFM_get_device_configuration(0)
-1074003964
>>> mirror.TLDFM_get_instrument_name()
-1073807360
```

Is there a way at least to have some logs more from ctypes, to understand where is the problem?

P.S.: in C it works, but I have to import the .lib file, not the .dll. In python when I try to import the .lib I have a system error saying, but I think this is normal.

Comment: What should `TLDFM_get_device_configuration()` return?

Comment: Consult the C prototype for the function, and assign proper `.argtypes` and `.restype` attributes to `mirror.TLDFM_get_device_configuration`; otherwise, ctypes makes assumptions about the arguments (int or pointer) and return type (int).  Read the [ctypes documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#specifying-the-required-argument-types-function-prototypes).

Comment: To me this actually looks like a VISA error code, although I can't find the exact one this corresponds to. This would mean that the dll is loading properly, but the instrument is not responding as expected. Additionally, I don't think python likes lib files - you have to work with dlls.